# Get Kafka Consumer partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I´m creating a KafkaConsumer and I need to know which partition has been assigned, to send to that particular partition the messages

```
final KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(java.util.List.of(topic));
```

I tried using the assignment after subscribe to the topic, but the list is empty

```
private Integer getPartition() {
    return List.ofAll(consumer.assignment())
        .filter(topicPartition -> topicPartition.topic().equals(topic))
        .map(TopicPartition::partition)
        .get();
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try calling `consumer.poll(0)` so an assignment happens? Otherwise, as you poll `ConsumerRecord`s, then those will have the partition information in them

Comment: But "sending to a particular partition" means you are coupling your consumer to a producer process, which should never be done. You can always use `producer.send("topic", partitionNumber...)` and `consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition))` rather than subscribing to achieve, this, though

Comment: This pattern is a very specific Throttling service where producer know consumer partition. So then I can scale my service wit h more consumers and each of them with a specific Throttling config

Comment: Okay... You can set topic quotas at the broker level rather than per client or partition, though. You can't scale consumers of a group beyond the number of partitions of the topic. In any case, assignment doesn't happen until you start a fetch request